# Getting Cluster Running State Using Ansible

Tags: google-cloud-platform, ansible

I have a playbook that performs some tasks on a GKE cluster. It works, but every now and again, the cluster will go into a "RECONCILING" state (we don't know why yet).

I want to add a task to wait for the cluster state to be in "RUNNING" before proceeding with the other tasks, in order to avoid tasks failing

This works:

```yaml
- name: Wait for cluster in RUNNING state
  shell:
    cmd: |
      gcloud container clusters describe {{ cluster_name }} --zone {{ gke_location }} --format json | jq .status --raw-output
  retries: 60
  delay: 60
  register: cluster_state
  until: cluster_state.stdout == "RUNNING"
```

But it's rather crude and I would like to use the [google.cloud](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/google/cloud/index.html) collection if possible rather than hacking something that just uses the `gcloud` binary under the hood

I've gotten as far as doing this:

```yaml
- name: Get clusters
  gcp_container_cluster_info:
    location: "{{ gke_location }}"
    project: "{{ project }}"
    auth_kind: serviceaccount
    service_account_file: "ansible-user.json"
  register: cluster_info
```

Which gives me a nice detailed resources list of all the clusters in my project.

However, based on the documentation on the [cluster_info](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/google/cloud/gcp_container_cluster_info_module.html) block, it does not appear I can filter for a single cluster, based on name and since I can't filter, I can't assume that the cluster in `resources[0]` will be the one I am looking for -- and even if it was, there's no guarantee it will be in the future.

How can I retrieve the cluster state (RUNNING, RECONCILING, etc) without using the `shell` or `command` modules (if it is even possible)?

**UPDATE**

I've been able to select my cluster from the list, but I cannot seem to get the `until` clause right

Here's the yaml I've been able to cobble together:

```yaml
- name: Get clusters info
  gcp_container_cluster_info:
    location: "{{ gke_location }}"
    project: "{{ project }}"
    auth_kind: serviceaccount
    service_account_file: "ansible-user.json"
  register: cluster_info

- debug:
    msg: "{{ cluster_info.resources | selectattr('name','==',cluster_name) | map(attribute='status') }}"

- name: Wait for cluster to be in RUNNING
  gcp_container_cluster_info:
    location: "{{ gke_location }}"
    project: "{{ project }}"
    auth_kind: serviceaccount
    service_account_file: "ansible-user.json"
  register: cluster_info
  retries: 60
  delay: 30
  until: (cluster_info.resources | selectattr('name','==', cluster_name) | map(attribute='status'))  == "RUNNING"
```

And here's the output

```
TASK [Debug] *******************************************************************

TASK [debug : Get clusters info] ***********************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [debug : debug] ***********************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": [
        "RUNNING"
    ]
}

TASK [debug : Wait for cluster to be in RUNNING] *******************************
FAILED - RETRYING: [localhost]: Wait for cluster to be in RUNNING (60 retries left).
...
```

I know I have two `gcp_container_cluster_info` blocks, this is just for debugging. If I can get this to work, I'll only need one.

You can see from the output that the state is correctly being retrieved using the filter:

`cluster_info.resources | selectattr('name','==',cluster_name) | map(attribute='status')`

(Feel free to tell me if there's a better way of doing this ^_^)

However, when trying to use that in the `until` clause it always seems to evaluate as false, so never continues, even though the previous debug proved the filter works. Any ideas why?

Comment: Have you looked into `- debug: var=cluster_info` to see what is hiding in there which may be relevant to you? I'd expect if g_c_c_i returns them all, then some use of `selectattr` can restrict it to just the cluster you care about

Comment: I was aware of debugging by using the debug block, but never heard about the `selectattr` clause. I'll take a look into that option

Comment: The **Return Values** section of the documentation you linked in question does mention an attribute named `status` => *The current status of this cluster.*

Comment: @seshadri_c the problem is that the module returns ALL of the clusters without the ability to filter. So I need to figure out how to filter the results. @mdaniel has suggested `selectattr`

Comment: I've updated the question with further details. I would appreciate if you could let me know your thoughts. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got it correct almost. The only thing is that the `selectattr` and `map` query is returning a list with 1 item, i.e.

```
    "msg": [
        "RUNNING"
    ]
```

That's why a string comparison `== "RUNNING"` will not work. We can either (i) use the index 0 (`list[0]`), to get that item in list *or* (ii) use the `item in list` syntax for this.

Here's is an example of using `item in list` syntax:

```
until: ("RUNNING" in cluster_info.resources | selectattr('name','==', cluster_name) | map(attribute='status'))
```

As you mentioned, you can have 1 task with `until` condition such as above:

```yaml
- name: Wait for cluster to be in RUNNING
  gcp_container_cluster_info:
    location: "{{ gke_location }}"
    project: "{{ project }}"
    auth_kind: serviceaccount
    service_account_file: "ansible-user.json"
  register: cluster_info
  retries: 60
  delay: 30
  until: ("RUNNING" in cluster_info.resources | selectattr('name','==', cluster_name) | map(attribute='status'))
```

Comment: Does ansible evaluate the pipes before the "in" part? i.e. does it do `cluster_info.resources | selectattr('name','==', cluster_name) | map(attribute='status'))` before doing `"RUNNING" in X`?

Comment: Before doing an `in` comparison, Ansible will evaluate the expression on the right completely. The presence of `"RUNNING"` to the left does not matter.

Comment: You mentioned that the other option was to using index [0]. How would that look? Would that be `"RUNNING in cluster_info.resources[0] | ...`

Comment: Couldn't test it, but It should be something like: `(cluster_info.resources | selectattr('name','==', cluster_name) | map(attribute='status'))[0] == "RUNNING"`.